# How can send 2 email per one hour using nodemailer in nodejs

Tags: node.js, timing, nodemailer

> ```
>  async.each(listofemails, function(to, callback){
> mailOptions.to = to;
> console.log(to);
> smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
>         if (err) { 
>             console.log('Sending to ' + to + ' failed: ' + err);
>             callback(err);
>         } else{ 
>             console.log('Sent to ' + to);
>             Company.update({status:'not sent'},{$set:{ status:'sent'}},function(error){
>               if (error) {console.log("error saving status"+error);}
>               else{console.log("status saved");}
>           });
>
>             callback();
> }
> });
> ```

setInterval(smtpTransport.sendMail,1000*30);

> ```
>    .
>
>
>
> `
> ```
>
> This is my code for sending email.
>   i want to send 10  emails like 2 emails per hour using nodemailer in nodejs

Comment: Make your question more descriptive.  Look into https://github.com/merencia/node-cron if that will help.

Comment: how many emails per day,and at what timings?

Comment: per day 10 emails ,2 emails per one hour

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using javascript, you can use the tools provided by your OS, to execute your node app every hour.

If you're on Linux, you can schedule the execution of your node app with `crontab` https://www.howtogeek.com/101288/how-to-schedule-tasks-on-linux-an-introduction-to-crontab-files/

If you're on Windows you can use `task scheduler` : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create a node script that can send a email on running once.

Then edit crontab by running **crontab -e** , and append the following line to the file :

```
0,30 * * * * node /home/ashwani/test/script.js
```

Now the OS will automatically run script.js every half hour i.e. twice every hour

In the above code 0 and 30 signify 0th minute and 30th minute of every hour.

To run it every half hour from 10 am till 2:30 pm, you can use following code :

```
0,30 10,11,12,13,14 * * * node /home/ashwani/test/script.js
```

For a better understanding, have a loot at https://crontab.guru/#0,30_10,11,12,13,14_*_*_*

Comment: but i need to send 10 emails per day ,with 2 per hour

Comment: check my updated answer now .The second code will run it 10 times  everyday starting from 10 am.

Comment: can u explain little bit more

Comment: 0,30 means 0th minute and 30th minute of every hour. 10,11,12,13,14 means 10th,11th,12th,13th,14th hour of every day.So your script will run on 0th minute of 10th hour i.e. 10:00 am.Then on 30th minute of 10th hour i.e. 10:30 am.Then on 0th minute of 11th hour i.e. 11:00 am ....and so on till 14:30.

Comment: @AswaniVs Kindly accept the answer if it solved your problem.